# Reading out a binary file

Tags: c, linux, binary, adc

I have some Analog to Digital Converter data that is automatically written in a binary file that I want to read out. In the instruction manual that came with the device, there is a sample C code that would do that, but I tried using it and it won't compile. Since this is the first time I am doing something like this or the first time I am using C, I need some help.

The manual says: The.CHN spectral data files contain the channel-by-channel contents of the MCB in 32-bit integer. The header is 32 bytes long. The next part of the file contains the spectrum stored as 32-bit integers. There are no record separators in the file. The number of spectrum records is determined by the number of channels in the spectrum.
The code given is:

```
/*Sample program compatible with Microsoft and Borland C*/
/* to read header and channel data from a .CHN data file. */
#include <stdio.h>

#define .CHN -1

main(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char *argv[];
{
    char acq_time[32]; /* buffer for time, date*/
    int f_type; /*.CHN file type*/
    unsigned int chan_offset,/* beginning channel number*/
    count, /*loop counter*/
    mca_num, /*1-4 are valid*/
    num_chans, /* no. of data channels*/
    num_writ, /* no. of bytes written out*/
    segment; /* segment number*/
    long int livetime, /*20 ms tics of livetime*/
    realtime, /*20 ms tics of realtime*/
    chan_data; /*stores channel data*/
    FILE *f_pointer;

    if(argc!=2){
        printf("USAGE: readchn filename.chn\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f_pointer = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    /* Header Data*/
    /* output header info from .CHN file*/
    /* read filetype -1 (.CHN) */

    fread(&f_type, sizeof(int), 1, f_pointer);
    if(f_type != .CHN) {
        printf("Not a valid file \n");
        return -1;
    }

    fread(&mca_num, sizeof(int), 1, f_pointer); /*MCA number*/
    fread(&segment, sizeof(int), 1, f_pointer); /* segment #*/
    fread(acq_time+12, sizeof(char), 1, f_pointer);/*start time*/
    fread(&realtime, sizeof(long), 1, f_pointer);/*20ms ticks*/
    fread(&livetime, sizeof(long), 1, f_pointer);/*20ms ticks*/
    fread(acq_time, sizeof(char), 2, f_pointer);/*start date*/
    fread(acq_time+2, sizeof(char), 3, f_pointer);/*start month*/
    fread(acq_time+5, sizeof(char), 3, f_pointer);/*start year*/
    fread(acq_time+8, sizeof(char), 2, f_pointer);/*start hour*/
    fread(acq_time+10, sizeof(char), 2, f_pointer);/*start mins*/
    fread(&chan_offset, sizeof(int), 1, f_pointer); /*offset*/
    fread(&num_chans, sizeof(int), 1, f_pointer); /*#channels*/

    printf("TYPE = %4i MCA# %2i\n", f_type, mca_num);
    printf("SEGMENT # %3i\n", segment);
    printf("REALTIME = %10li seconds\n", realtime/50);
    printf("LIVETIME = %10li seconds\n", livetime/50);

    printf("DATA COLLECTED AT ");
    fwrite(acq_time+8, sizeof(char), 2, stdout);
    putchar(':');
    fwrite(acq_time+10, sizeof(char), 2, stdout);
    putchar(':');
    fwrite(acq_time+12, sizeof(char), 2, stdout);

    printf("ON");
    fwrite(acq_time, sizeof(char), 2, stdout);
    putchar('-');
    fwrite(acq_time+2, sizeof(char), 3, stdout);
    putchar('-');
    fwrite(acq_time+5, sizeof(char), 2, stdout);

    printf("\nSTARTING CHANNEL = %6in", chan_offset);
    printf("\nNUMBER OF CHANNELS = %6i\n\n", num_chans);

    /* Channel Data*/
    /* Output channel data from .CHN file*/

    printf("CHANNEL DATA\n");
    for(count = 0; count < num_chans; count++){
        if((count % 6) ==0)
            printf("n%7i", count);
            fread(&chan_data, sizeof(long), 1, f_pointer);
            printf("%11i", chan_data);
            }
    fcloseall();
}
```

The given code wouldn't compile in XCode.

Given the file structure, is there a way to look at the file (the ones and zeroes) from command line? I tried using

```
 xxd -b <filename>
```

but the output does not look consistent with the file description, there is no distinct header. Here are first few lines of the output:

```
0000000: 11111111 11111111 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000  ......
0000006: 00110001 00110001 10111101 11011101 00110011 00000000  11..3.
000000c: 01100111 01000100 00101100 00000000 00110010 00110011  gD,.23
0000012: 01000110 01100101 01100010 00110001 00110111 00110001  Feb171
0000018: 00110001 00110110 00110101 00110000 00000000 00000000  1650..
000001e: 00000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
0000024: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
000002a: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
0000030: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you learning from the K&R book by any chance? You should know that with all due respect to Dennis Ritchie, the book about ANSI C (As well as ANSI C itself) is not what the current iteration of language looks like. For instance you can't omit the return type for main, nor should you specify function parameters like you did (so called K&R style).

Comment: It looks like the posted code might be assuming that `sizeof(int) == 2`.

Comment: And if it doesn't compile, you should include **the error**, verbatim, in the post. One blatant mistake is `.CHN`. A macro name must be a valid identifier. It means it can only be compromised of `_`, digits and letters.

Comment: This is not from a book, but from an instruction manual that came with the device. It does look a little outdated.

Comment: Then code is more than a little outdated.  It is written in antiquated style, and it does not comply with even the original C standard (C89), now about 28 years old.  The code only needs about two teaks to *compile* cleanly, but it's not at all clear to me that it will work as intended when built with a compiler other than the obsolete ones that it claims to be compatible with.

Comment: .CHN is not a macro, but the file type? Is there a way to display the content of the file in the terminal, so I could write my own parser?

Comment: `#define .CHN` is an attempt to create a preprocessor macro.

Comment: Tip: with the dozen or so `fread(&some_variable, sizeof(some_type), 1, f_pointer);`, a reviewer is obliged to check if the type of `some_variable` and the `some_type` match.  Reduce mistakes and save time, use `fread(&some_variable, sizeof some_variable, 1, f_pointer);` as in `fread(&mca_num, sizeof mca_num, 1, f_pointer);`

Comment: Since you have device documentation, I'm inclined to think that it has detailed specifications for the data format, with the C code serving as exactly what the docs say: an *example* of software to read it.  I suspect that it may be less work to write new code based on the format spec, maybe clarified by the example code, than to try to rescue the example code itself.

Comment: Note: in your binary dump the header is the first 5 lines plus the first two entries of the 6th line.  If you don't care about the information in the header, just skip those first 32 bytes and read the values that follow (which are all 0 in the portion of the dump you posted).  You can figure you the header format by looking at the code and working through it with the assumption that `sizeof(int) ==2`. Or fix the code using @JohnBollinger's suggestions and change the types `int` and `long` to `int16_t` and `int32_t` (or something along those lines).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I am a complete novice for this kind of thing. Does the output from xxd -b <filename> seem right? I am confused, since I expected to see only 1's and 0's.

Comment: @AndreaFodor, the left column of the `xxd` output gives offsets from the beginning of the file, in hexadecimal.  The last column gives an interpretation of the data as ASCII characters.  The middle six columns present the binary data you were expecting.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I modified the types as you said, and it works. Thanks a lot!